# Using if statement in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I would like to do these actions step by step:

1. first DB update
2. copy file
3. unlink file
4. second DB update

It is working, but I don't know if my code is correct/valid:

```
$update1 = $DB->query("UPDATE...");

  if ($update1)
  {
    if (copy("..."))
    {
      if (unlink("..."))
      {
        $update2 = $DB->query("UPDATE ..."); 
      }         
    }
  }
```

Is it possible to use if statement this way?

I found that it is usually used with *PHP operators* and *PHP MySQL select*, for example:

```
$select = $DB->row("SELECT number...");
  if ($select->number == 2) {
  ...
  }
```

Comment: `if` is used pretty much whenever there is *conditional branching* that needs to occur. It doesn't matter where the value comes from (and yes, SQL is one popular data source). In any case, see the documentation for whichever method to see what the results mean. You may also want to ensure that update2 "succeeded" and/or use a transaction or optimistic concurrency.

Comment: If you have working code and you want to improve it, consider asking on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, your ifs work fine. What would look and flow better would be using a function like this:

```
function processThings() {
    // make sure anything you use in here is either passed in or global

    if(!$update1)
        return false;

    if(!$copy)
        return false;

    if(!$unlink)
        return false;

    if(!$update2)
        return false;

    // you made it!
    return true;
}
```

make sure you call $DB as a global variable, plus pass in whatever strings you need etc etc